# Kotlin - generic param in List - Java and Kotlin mix

Tags: java, android, generics, parameters, kotlin

I have the following problem. I have interface written in Kotlin that has a Listener in it:

```
interface Listener {

    fun onCountriesSuccess(countries: List<CountrySupportDto>)

    fun onCountriesFailure(t: Throwable)

}
```

and I have a class in Java that uses this interface as anonymous instance:

```
private InteractorCountriesNetwork.Listener getCountriesInteractorListener() {
return new InteractorCountriesNetwork.Listener() {
  @Override
  public void onCountriesSuccess(List<CountrySupportDto> countryRealmList) {
    if (view != null) {
      view.updateCountriesList(countryRealmList);
      view.hideProgress();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCountriesFailure(Throwable t) {
    if (view != null) {
      view.showFailure(t);
    }
  }
};
}
```

And Android studio complains about this method signature:

```
@Override
public void onCountriesSuccess(List<CountrySupportDto> countryRealmList) {
  ...
}
```

The complaint is as following:

> 'onCountiresSuccess(List< CountrySupportDto >)' in 'Anonymous class derived from (...).Listener' clashes with 'onCountriesSuccess(List< ? extends CountrySupportDto >)' in (...).Listener'; both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other.

Can you please tell me what's wrong with this code? Also, the class must be implemented in Java, unfortunately.

Comment: Changing the signature of the Java method to take a `List<? extends CountrySupportDto>` will probably fix the error.

Comment: I tried your code and it seems to work perfectly fine. I use gradle 4 and IntelliJ. Do you have the same problem when you build it with gradle `./gradlew clean build --info`?